# looping through an array, wierd output

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have an array that looks like this,

```
    Array
(
    [candidate_id] => 1
    [first_name] => Simon
    [surname] => Ainley
    [gender] => male
    [talent] => presenter
    [DOB] => 1987-06-12
    [Location] => Huddersfield
    [height] => 6' 3"
    [eyes] => blue
    [hair] => brown
    [hair_length] => short
    [accents] => Native english
    [training] => none
    [unions] => Actors guild
    [date_created] => 2011-10-11 00:00:00
)
```

However  when I don the following,

```
<?php foreach ($results as $k => $v) : ?>
    <?php print_r($v); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Using this I am getting output,

```
1 S A m p 1 H 6 b b s N n A 2
```

Comment: That is definitely not your array: http://ideone.com/KdsMV

Comment: @WesleyMurch: -Or- not the code :)

Comment: did yo tried with simple echo?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you try and echo an array element thats actually a string. eg.

```
$string = "hello";
echo $string[1]; // echos "e"
```

Make sure the structure of $results is what you think it is and you are using print_r() on the correct variable.

See also: [String access and modification by character <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).